# Json 2 usable format

Tags: json, tcl

I just started yesterday working with TCL. And i am trying to get the longitude and latitude from a call to the google maps API.
I am using the following URL (with my key ofcourse)
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=amsterdam&key=[MYKEY]

The return is json and i convert this with json2dict. This give me a dict with only "results" and "status" as keys.

How am i going to get the long and lat from the results? I tried the dict filter, but i cant really get it to work

```
set lat [dict filter $dict {k v} {expr {$k eq "lat"}}]
```

In javascript it would be as easy as something like this

```
result[0].geometry.bounds.lat
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing a bit at your json structure, hence the structure of the dict, but it's probably something like this:

```
package req json
set js {{"result":[{"geometry":{"bounds":{"lat":42,"long":24}}}]}}
set d [json::json2dict $js]
```

then

```
set results [dict get $d result]
set item [lindex $results 0]
set lat [dict get $item geometry bounds lat]       ;# => 42
```

or, in one line

```
set lat [dict get [lindex [dict get $d result] 0] geometry bounds lat]
```

---

ok, downloaded and build [rl_json](https://github.com/RubyLane/rl_json)

```
$ sudo apt install tcl-dev
$ git clone https://github.com/RubyLane/rl_json.git
$ cd rl_json
$ ./configure && make && sudo make install
```

then

```
$ tclsh
% package require rl_json
0.9.11
% set js {{"result":[{"geometry":{"bounds":{"lat":42,"long":24}}}]}}
{"result":[{"geometry":{"bounds":{"lat":42,"long":24}}}]}
% json get $js result
invalid command name "json"
% rl_json::json
Wrong # of arguments.  Must be "method ?arg ...?"
% namespace import rl_json::json
% json get $js result
{geometry {bounds {lat 42 long 24}}}
% json get $js result 0
geometry {bounds {lat 42 long 24}}
% json get $js result 0 geometry bounds lat
42
```

Pretty straightforward.

Comment: You should accept the answer if it solves your problem, so the poster gets credit for it.

Comment: The rl_json library (recommended for working with JSON in modern Tcl code) would make this easier.

Comment: I recommend [tdom](http://tdom.org) for working with JSON in "old" and "modern" Tcl code ;)

Answer (score 1):

> result[0].geometry.bounds.lat

You can have the same benefits (and many more goodies) using [tdom](http://tdom.org)'s JSON support:

```
% package req tdom
0.9.1
% set js {{"result":[{"geometry":{"bounds":{"lat":42,"long":24}}}]}}
{"result":[{"geometry":{"bounds":{"lat":42,"long":24}}}]}
% set d [dom parse -json $js]
domDoc0x7fc98b700770
% $d selectNodes {string(//result/*[1]/geometry/bounds/long)}
24
% $d selectNodes {string(//result/*[1]/geometry/bounds/lat)}
42
```

This assumes that you have tdom 0.9+. XPath positional access is one-based.